# Entity Framework Update Database On Model Change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I am currently using auto-migrations with the following powershell console commands:
add-migration 
update-database

I would like to know if there is an option to update the database automatically if the model changes (DbContext) without using the console commands.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext,Configuration>());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

This causes the database migrations to the latest version when the data context is created at code runtime.